# Warning when trying to update firebase realtime database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app with Firebase where a user logs into their account. The only problem is, when I want to log out, I want to erase some info I have previously saved on the database, but for some reason the database doesn't get updated and this warning message appears:

> Error: [database/permission denied] Client doesn't have permission to acess the desired data

My guess is that that's happening because the update code doesn't have enough time to execute the instruction. My code looks like this (it's triggered by a button press):

```
onPressLogout = () => {
  const { navigation } = this.props;
  const userId = auth().currentUser.uid;

  database().ref(`users/${userId}`).update({ tokens: '' });
  auth().signOut().then(() => navigation.navigate('Auth'));
}
```

Any help's appreciated.

Comment: usually it means your security rules are not configuared properly to access the data. can you share your security rules ?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal my rules are like this
`"rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth !== null"
}`

Comment: If you have additional information, you should edit the question with the edit link to add that.  Don't bury information in comments.

Comment: Please make sure you are able to log a valid value for `userId`.  We can't see what you're working with here.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the signout happens before the `update` operation, which then fails because the user is no longer signed in.

Easiest is to wait until the write is completed before signing out. You can do this either with `await`:

```
await database().ref(`users/${userId}`).update({ tokens: '' });
auth().signOut().then(() => navigation.navigate('Auth'));
```

Or with a more classic `then()`:

```
database().ref(`users/${userId}`).update({ tokens: '' }).then(()=> {
  auth().signOut().then(() => navigation.navigate('Auth'));
})
```

Comment: While the second approach certanly takes care of the updating issue, for some reason it didn't solved the warning one, it keeps appearing. Now, I added a `console.log()` before the `auth` and that seems to have fixed it, altough it's a clunky way. Maybe there's another, more "fancy" way?

Comment: My feeling is that the warning may come from somewhere else in that case. For example: are you attaching a listener somewhere else in the code that requires the user to be authenticated. If so, that listener will be canceled when you sign the user out. To prevent the logging that indicates that, you'll want to remove the listener before signing out in that case. But since you're navigating away right after that, the net benefit is pretty small.

Comment: After a little bit of digging, I found a listener in another screen. It takes care of recieving notifications that the user might recieve when logged in. My way of getting rid of this listener is like this: `componentWillUnmount() { if (this.screenListener) this.screenListener.remove(); }`. Since the error appears with it like this, I suppose that this isn't good enough to close the listener. Any sugestions?

Comment: Sorry, we're missing context, and it changes the question significantly. You might want to reproduce the problem of the listener not being removed with just that other screen, and post a question with just that code.

Answer (score 0):

React is asynchronous, so it doesn't wait for line to be executed in 100% and instead it executes further code. Usege of `await` should do the job:

```js
async onPressLogout(){
  const { navigation } = this.props;
  const userId = auth().currentUser.uid;

  await database().ref(`users/${userId}`).update({ tokens: '' });
  auth().signOut().then(() => navigation.navigate('Auth'));
}
```